# Largest block (measured in Bitcoins)

Tags: blockchain, block

What is the block in the blockchain with the most Bitcoins transacted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say that I'm certain of it, but this is the largest block I've ever seen:

[`00000000000000fb62bbadc0a9dcda556925b2d0c1ad8634253ac2e83ab8382f` aka nr 153509](https://blockchain.info/block-index/168616/00000000000000fb62bbadc0a9dcda556925b2d0c1ad8634253ac2e83ab8382f)

It has a total output volume of **607,176.29050282 BTC**, primarily because of [this 550k transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/29a3efd3ef04f9153d47a990bd7b048a4b2d213daaa5fb8ed670fb85f13bdbcf?currency=HKD).